# Is TListView OwnerData OnData event leaking memory?

Tags: listview, delphi, c++builder, tlistview

I am using `TListView` in virtual mode (`OwnerData` set to `true`) and that is simple enough. `TListView` is in `vsReport` view style and uses main Caption and SubItems. The event code for `OnData` is simple (the code is C++ Builder but you'll figure it out if you use Delphi):

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::ListView1Data(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item)
{
Item->Caption     = MyList[Item->Index].Name;
Item->SubItems->Add(MyList[Item->Index].Status);
}
```

All good so far, but I am puzzled by `SubItems->Add` - is that a memory leak to continuously add SubItems like that (also goes for Caption)?

Am I supposed to free the memory in an another event (which I haven't found yet)?

Comment: This could be relevant: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/93/297437.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not a memory leak. The framework allocated the `SubItems` object, and it deallocates it when it has finished using it.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Internally, `TListView` maintains a single physical `TListItem` object when running in virtual mode.  It reuses and clears that object whenever the `OnData` event needs to be triggered.  You do not need to free any of the `TListItem` data manually.